# WebKit implementation for iOS in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, webkit

Is there any way to use WebKit for developing iOS applications in xCode?  I'm pretty sure you can use WebKit for making Mac applications, but how about iOS ones?

Comment: Now you can with iOS 8.0 :) https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/ObjC_classic/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000745

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just drag out a UIWebView from the Library. You have less control over the content but it works to display webpages and javascript. However it may or may not suit your needs, depending on what you're looking for—you haven't specified.

Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Surely this is wrong? UIWebView is nothing like WebKit - WebKit is a full C++ and obj-c library that provides detailed access to web rendering. UIWebView is a relatively slow, out-of-date (it's usually a version or two behind WebKit) renderer that you can't customize. No?

Comment: It's still "using WebKit"…to be fair, the OP's question wasn't very clear. It took it to mean a WebKit-vs-Gecko type of question, rather than an I-want-access-to-the-actual-rendering approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my open source code here as a start project : https://github.com/sylverb/CIALBrowser